# html tag in childNodes (how can i get NodesValue)

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<p title="The test paragraph">This is a sample of some <b>HTML you might<br>have</b> in your document</p>
txt=document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


alert("<p>The text from the intro paragraph: " + txt + "</p>");
```

it doesn't work.

How can I get the childNodes.nodevalue "This is a sample of some HTML you might have in your document"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0],
    txt = p.innerText || p.textContent;

alert(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

I try you example and it is work fine, but you should replase "" in etElementsByTagName("p") by ''.
My code is:

```
    <p title="The test paragraph">This is a sample of some <b>HTML you might<br>have</b> in your document</p>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);"/>
```